# Return Element based on matching criteria from Stream

Tags: java, filter, collections, java-stream

I have a list of custom object AllData. I would like to return one element from this list that matches a specific criteria (widgetId = 58). How would i use stream/filter/collections to return single AllData object matching my criteria. I have tried the below, however i get *NoSuchElementException.*

```
AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDbInstance(MyContext.getContext());
List<AllData> allDataList = db.allDataDao().getAllDataList();
AllData allData = allDataList.stream().findFirst().filter(e -> e.getMyTicker().getWidgetId() == 58).get();
```

Comment: You're calling `findFirst()` which will remove all the elements but the first one. Is this what you intended? 
What's the data type for `getWidgetId()` ? How do you know the id 58 is present?

Comment: thanks, the answer that was provided by Deadpool is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `filter` the list first and the use `findFirst`

```
AllData allData = allDataList.stream()
       .filter(e -> e.getMyTicker().getWidgetId() == 58)
       .findFirst().get();
```

I would recommend to use [orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to avoid NoSuchElementException - if there is no value present in Optional

Answer (score 0):

What happens if nothing is returned?  You would want a default value to fall back on and also call findFirst() after filter(). Here you go:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    MyObject object = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getMyTicker().getWidgetId() == 58).findFirst().orElse(null);
}

public static class MyObject {
    private Ticker myTicker;

    public Ticker getMyTicker() {
        return myTicker;
    }
}

public static class Ticker {
    private int widgetId;

    public int getWidgetId() {
        return this.widgetId;
    }
}
```

Comment: MyObject object = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getMyTicker().getWidgetId() == 58).findFirst();


".orElse(null)" is unnecessary, as findFirst returns Optional.

Comment: Correct, findFirst returns an optional which means MyObject object = list.stream().filter(e -> e.getMyTicker().getWidgetId() == 58).findFirst(); won’t compile MyObject object is not an optional. You either have to do Optional<MyObject> object or append the orElse(null) to the stream to avoid it.